# Unable to install libmotif4

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

While installing dependencies for Oracle 11g setup on Ubuntu, I got the following error:

```
Package libmotif4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

However the following packages replace it:
libxm4:i386 libuil4:i386 libmrm4:i386 libxm4 libuil4 libmrm4 libmotif-common

E: Package 'libmotif4' has no installation candidate
```

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libmotif4 is not present in latest Ubuntu 16.04, due to which this error is occurring. For workaround I downloaded libmotif4 which was compatible with previous ubuntu 15.10 from http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libmotif4

After download, we just need to install the packages which are suggested in the error using apt-get install command

> libxm4:i386 libuil4:i386 libmrm4:i386 libxm4 libuil4 libmrm4 libmotif-common

Comment: Please note that this link are no longer valid. Are there any replacements? - credit to @fradsham for noticing this.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to fix this on Ubuntu 16.04 myself.  I did the following:

Navigate to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libmotif4/2.3.4-8ubuntu1 and download the .deb file.

Run the following from the directory where the file was downloaded to:

```
sudo dpkg -i libmotif4_2.3.4-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

During this process it will complain abot not having libmrm4, libuil4, and libxm4 in that order.

Now simply run the following command to fix the unmet dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

You should be up and running.  As of June 1, 2017, the link above was good.  Hopefully it can last awhile longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install the latest libmotif4 deb available for your architecture from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libmotif4)

Or in your case just run,

```
sudo dpkg -i http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/motif/libmotif4_2.3.4-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and continue with your Oracle 11g setup.

Comment: Please note that this link are no longer valid. Are there any replacements? - credit to @fradsham for noticing this.

Answer (score -1):

On ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
sudo su

echo 'deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libmotif4
```

**Optional:** to disable the Ubuntu Extra Apt Repo:

```
mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra.list.backup

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Mixing base repositories of different Ubuntu releases is asking for trouble. -1